# H2 Embedded Database tables not shown in Intellij Database Client

Tags: java, database, intellij-idea, h2

I'm learning how to implement a database into a music player application, and decided to use the embedded H2 database for my implementation.

```
public class H2EmbeddedDB {
public H2EmbeddedDB() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/data/musicAppDB", "sa", "");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        /*
        String createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE PLAYLISTS " +
                                "(playlistID INTEGER not NULL, " +
                                " playlistName VARCHAR(255), " +
                                " musicToContinuePath VARCHAR(255), " +
                                " durationToContinue INTEGER)";
        st.execute(createTableSQL);
        */

        String sql = "INSERT INTO PLAYLISTS " + "VALUES (123456789, 'Zara', 'C:\\Music', 18)";
        st.executeUpdate(sql);
        ResultSet rs;
        rs = st.executeQuery("select * from playlists");
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("playlistName"));
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Just a simple test class, I commented out the create table after the table is created. Everything works fine, the application prints out 'Zara' like it should, but I cannot find the table in the Intellij Database Tool.

[How I'm importing the database]
https://i.gyazo.com/e2c1360729d53f837ffe3195290db7fa.png

[Not showing anything in the DB]
https://gyazo.com/4ddc9cea065bd928471aff0805130f73

I know where it is storing the database, it's in my user folder/data, and I've tried putting the absolute path to it when connecting with intellij client. The connection test succeeds as well.

Comment: Did you try to create a bug here? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: The same. Did you solve the problem?